# How to define this kind of decision variables in CPLEX

Tags: cplex, opl

I'm new to CPLEX, I wonder how to define decision variables like `xijk` but only those with subscript `i < j` or `i ≠ j` using OPL.

The code is like

```
int jobsNum = ...;
int machinesNum = ...;

range jobs = 0..jobsNum-1
range machines = 0..machinesNum-1;

dvar boolean x[jobs][jobs][machines];
```

`x[jobs][jobs][machines]` is the relative processing sequence of job i and job j on machine k, but if I put it like this it will introduce some redundant variables, so I wonder if I can write something like

```
dvar boolean x[i in jobs][j in jobs: j < i][machines];
```

Comment: Please provide examples of your code

Comment: @Federico Navarrete Hi, I've edited my question and provided a simple example, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me give you an example

```
int jobsNum = 3;
int machinesNum = 4;

range jobs = 0..jobsNum-1;
range machines = 0..machinesNum-1;

tuple t
{
int i;
int j;
}

{t} transitions={<i,j> | ordered i,j in jobs};

dvar boolean x[transitions][machines];

subject to
{
x[<1,2>][1]==1;
}
```